# get file name from s3 in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash

I have an s3  bucket from where I am taking CSV file and uploading into ES. 
I am stuck on how to get file name which I have in s3 because I am using the s3 file name as Index name.
My config file -

```
input{
    s3{
    bucket => "***"
    access_key_id => "**"
    secret_access_key => "***"
    region => "**"

}
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns  => [ "name","uid","startdate","enddate"]

    }
    mutate {convert =>[uid , "integer"]}

      date {
      match => [ "startdate", "ISO8601", "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss","YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm" ]
      target => "startdate"
      locale => "en"
      timezone => "Asia/Dubai"
    }

      date {
      match => [ "enddate", "ISO8601", "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm","YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:s" ]
      target => "enddate"
      locale => "en"
      timezone => "Asia/Dubai"
    }
      mutate {
    add_field => {
      "index_name" => "%{[@metadata][s3][key]}"
    }

  }

  }

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "%{index_name}"
    }
    stdout{}

}
```

Comment: `%{[@metadata][s3][key]}` should do the job, doesn't it? Also note that it's not a good idea to ask a question in [Github issues](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-s3/issues/122).

Comment: actually yes its working , i make changes in config and not checked and posted here .